# Why wont docker allow me to execute a binary file without an interactive session?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am familiar with docker but have reached a road block. I am trying to call an executable from the terminal without running an interactive session. I can currently get this done by exectuing the following two commands:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/face/:/home/openface-build algebr/openface:latest 
build/bin/FeatureExtraction -f ./face/officespace.mp4
```

I am trying to  write a command that looks like the following:

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/face/:/home/openface-build algebr/openface:latest ./build/bin/FeatureExtraction -f ./face/officespace.mp4
```

However upon exectuion, I am getting an error saying I cannot execute the binary file. I also am getting this if I try to run

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/face/:/home/openface-build algebr/openface:latest bash
```

This is the contents from my docker image inspect command

```
 "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "1bc488685a5e",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "ENTRYPOINT [\"/bin/bash\"]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:c7625f34563c9af6cc837f8ccc202a61070a5f702888a06f15e4184b497da049",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/home/openface-build",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/bash"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "Edgar Aroutiounian <edgar.factorial@gmail.com>"
            }
        },
        "DockerVersion": "18.03.1-ce",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:c7625f34563c9af6cc837f8ccc202a61070a5f702888a06f15e4184b497da049",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/home/openface-build",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/bash"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "Edgar Aroutiounian <edgar.factorial@gmail.com>"
            }
        },
```

```
Also it should be noted that in order to replicate this problem, I had to copy the original contents of container $ /home/openface-build/ to localhost$ ~/face so that they merge as a union
```

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the [Dockerfile for that base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/algebr/openface/dockerfile) it ends with the line

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

This means that any command you pass as arguments to `docker run` will actually be given as arguments to `bash` -- for your `docker run` command, Docker is actually running

```
/bin/bash build/bin/FeatureExtraction -f ./face/officespace.mp4
```

That file presumably isn't a shell script, which leads to the error message you're getting.

The default behavior for the unmodified `ubuntu` image is in fact to launch a shell on startup, so the upstream author should probably just delete that line from their Dockerfile; it has no practical effect and causes problems for you.

The awkward way to work around this is to provide the binary you want to run as the entrypoint instead.

```
docker run ... \
  --entrypoint build/bin/FeatureExtraction \
  algebr/openface:latest \
  -f ./face/officespace.mp4
```